# How to select any item from AutoCompleteTextView programmatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // code...
    list.add("First");
    list.add("Second");
    list.add("Third");
    list.add("Forth");
    list.add("Fifth");
    autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.drop_down, list);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adpater);
}
```

> then, after adding some strings to
> ArrayList and linking that list with autoCompleteTextView using Adapter.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setSelection(3);
```

Now I want any of my item getting selected automatically, once I open this activity. I treid setSelection() method, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to pass `false` as second argument to setText() method.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setText("First", false);
```

If we don't pass second arguiment `"false"` as a filter to `setText()` method, it will clear all the entries inside list and will keep just one entry. that we set as using `setText()` method.

Answer (score 0):

your selected value will store selectedItem

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // code...
    autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete);
   
    list.add("First");
    list.add("Second");
    list.add("Third");
    list.add("Forth");
    list.add("Fifth");
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.drop_down, list);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adpater);
autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
  String selectedItem = autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: threshold() is not any method for AutoCompleteTextView. Actual method is setThreshold(), but that is also not working.

Comment: it was type mistake because I wrote it with kotlin that's why.  but it should work I have given you the code from my current project.

Comment: Ok. but that didn't help. Actually, I found the solution and posted the same. You can check. Thanks anyways for your initiative.